# SQL help needed for my data model

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Here is my data model

```
ProjectsTable   DocumentTable   DocumentVersionsTable   UserTable   DocumentVersionActivityTable
ProjectID(PK)   DocumentID(PK)  DocumentVersionID(PK)   UserID      ActivityID(PK)
                ProjectID(FK)   DocumentID(PK)                      DocumentVersionID(FK)
                                                                    UserID(FK)
                                                                    DateOfActivity
```

What need to get is all of the distinct Projects where a specific user created a DocumentVersionActivity, sorted by DateOfActivity descending (i.e. so that the most recent document versions edited, for example, will reflect as a Project recently edited.

I've used the following, which successfully tracks the DocumentVersion to the Project, but I'm not sure how take it to the next step by limiting it by User and sorting based on the DocumentVersionActivityTable

```
select a.projectid 
   b.documentid 
   c.documentversionid 
from DocumentVersions c 
       join Documents b on b.ID = c.DocumentID 
       join Projects a on a.ID = b.ProjectID
```

I'm doing this for a ASP.Net Web API project using EF 6.0 so if I can capture these as easily or faster without SQL, I'd love to see that too.

Thanks.

FINAL EDIT:
The code that I'm going with (note: keep commented out items for information).  Thanks Leslie:

```
SELECT a.ID as projectid ,
  -- b.ID as haldocumentid, 
 --  c.ID as documentversionid,
   --d.projectcomponentActivityID as projectcomponentactivityid,
 --  e.id as userid,
   max(d.datetimeofactivity) as latestdate
FROM DocumentVersions c 
   INNER JOIN halDocuments b ON b.ID = c.DocumentID 
   INNER JOIN Projects a ON a.ID = b.ProjectID
   INNER JOIN Documentversionprojectcomponentactivities d ON 
   d.AssociatedDocumentVersionID = c.ID
   INNER JOIN Users e ON e.id = d.userid
WHERE e.id = 3 and d.DateTimeOfActivity >= DATEADD(d, -30, getdate())
group by a.id --, b.id, c.id, e.id
order by latestdate desc`
```

Comment: Cool, glad you worked it out, sorry I wasn't able to get back to you last night.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

```
SELECT 
  --a.ID as projectid, 
  b.ID as documentid, 
  c.ID as documentversionid,
  d.projectcomponentActivityID as projectcomponentactivityid,
  e.id as userid,
  MAX(d.DatetimeOfActivity)
FROM DocumentVersions c 
  INNER JOIN Documents b ON b.ID = c.DocumentID 
  --INNER JOIN Projects a ON a.ID = b.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN Documentversionprojectcomponentactivities d 
    ON d.AssociatedDocumentVersionID = c.ID
  INNER JOIN Users e ON e.id = d.userid
WHERE e.id = 2
GROUP BY 
  --a.ID as projectid, 
  b.ID as documentid, 
  c.ID as documentversionid,
  d.projectcomponentActivityID as projectcomponentactivityid,
  e.id as userid
--ORDER BY d.DatetimeOfActivity DESC
```

Comment: @Leslie....thanks I made some tweaks but this is VERY close to what I was looking for.  One more follow up question: any way to get the most recent date easily vs. all of the dates sorted?

Comment: Add MAX(DateOfActivity) to your select statement and GROUP BY the other fields

Comment: Thanks Leslie...So close thanks to you.  Can we eliminate all projectids? See my latest EDIT #2

Comment: I don't see an edit. I will edit your version with what I think you want.

Comment: My last comment was confusing.   What I'm looking for is to get only the projectids that have the max date (so the projectids are distinct).  The latest code groups all the ids so there can be duplicate projectids which ideally would be removed.